# Does private RSA, DSA or ECDSA key in pem-format contain public key?

Tags: openssl, public-key, ecdsa

I use hardcoded ec-kyes for testing my application.
There is example for ecdsa:

```
const char pem_ecdsa_prv_key[] = {
    "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    "MHcCAQEEIAGOaT3/9PJxSIFKPbvEhj61jY3CGPsgA46IVZlvIlnGoAoGCCqGSM49\n"
    "AwEHoUQDQgAE6Dw87+AYjRQzNsb3RmANmNENCZArERfCKZ5M9+2S/yomA6fmFdeb\n"
    "XNXeV066Nk4jnuwF1ZKqCBoMBjsnm0jlCw==\n"
    "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
};

const char pem_ecdsa_pub_key[] = {
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE6Dw87+AYjRQzNsb3RmANmNENCZAr\n"
    "ERfCKZ5M9+2S/yomA6fmFdebXNXeV066Nk4jnuwF1ZKqCBoMBjsnm0jlCw==\n"
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
};
```

It has been generated with help ssh-keygen utility.
I need to convert this pem-strings to openssl EC_KEY format to use it with sign/verify openssl functions. 
I do conversion like this(error checking has been omitted):

```
EC_KEY *ecdsa = NULL;
BIO *bio= NULL;

/* read pem string to openssl bio format */
bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pem_ecdsa_prv_key,sizeof(pem_ecdsa_prv_key));

/* convert bio to ec_key */
ecdsa = EC_KEY_new();
PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey(bio, &ecdsa, NULL, NULL);
```

Now I do this conversion for `pem_ecdsa_prv_key` and for `pem_ecdsa_pub_key`.
Should i do this only for private key array, because it contains public key too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the public key exactly the same way but you use the [PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY.html) instead of PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey.

e.g.

```
/* read pem string to openssl bio format */
bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pem_ecdsa_pub_key,sizeof(pem_ecdsa_pub_key));

/* convert bio to ec_key */
ecdsa = PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

(note, you don't need to allocate EC_KEY first in either the PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY or PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey call)

Also, the private key normally contains the [public key](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105847/107320).  If you load the private key, you can use the EC_KEY for all private key / public key usages.  If you load the public key, you can only use it for public key usages.